# Having trouble combining INNER JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having some trouble combining some inner joins in the following piece of code:

```
SELECT Table1FakeName.Field1
FROM Table1 AS Table1FakeName
INNER JOIN Table2 AS Table2FakeName ON Table1FakeName.Field2 = Table2FakeName.Field2
INNER JOIN Table3 AS Table3FakeName ON Table2FakeName.Field2 = Table3FakeName.Field2;
```

I am getting the following error:

> Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'Table2FakeName.Field2
>       INNER JOIN Table3 AS Table3FakeName ON Table2FakeName.Field2 = Table3FakeName.Field2'

PS: Please do not vote down on this post.  If you have a reason for doing so, discuss it in the comments section.

Comment: No error with this on SQL Server. Which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using the Access database.

Comment: Are you sure that table Table2 has a column Field2 and Table3 has a column Field2?

Comment: All three tables have more than 2 columns.

Comment: Do the field types match?

Comment: Yes, they are both type varchar(6).

Comment: Can you try to put the ON conditions into brackets? Like this: ON (Table1FakeName.Field2 = Table2FakeName.Field2)

Comment: It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: If this is not the real query (fake alias and col names), perhaps posting the real query/column names might shed some light on the problem? Could one of the aliases you are using be a keyword or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Table1FakeName.Field1
FROM ((Table1 AS Table1FakeName
INNER JOIN Table2 AS Table2FakeName 
      ON Table1FakeName.Field2 = Table2FakeName.Field2)
INNER JOIN Table3 AS Table3FakeName
      ON Table2FakeName.Field2 = Table3FakeName.Field2);
```

In Access you need an additional bracket before the FROM clause for every extra table you join, and one closing bracket for the JOIN's ON clause.